# Mockito returns a list of null elements except of the first, although I've initialized every element

Tags: java, list, unit-testing, mockito

I wanted to check if **mock JPA repository** will return all the elements. I've created 3 entities and initialized them, then created list and put these models into this list. After that, wrote statment:

```
when(pasteboxJPARepository.findAll()).thenReturn(entities);
```

And it seems, that after calling findAll() method, I'll get list of entities. **Yes, I get it, but all the elements're null except of the first, don't know what it can be(the console screen at the end)**.

**Test class**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class PasteboxServiceTests {

@Autowired
PasteboxService pasteboxService;
@MockBean
PasteboxJPARepository pasteboxJPARepository;

@Test
void testFindAll(){

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime expTime = now.plusSeconds(45);
    LocalDateTime expTime1 = now.plusSeconds(40);
    LocalDateTime expTime2 = now.plusSeconds(35);

    PasteboxEntity entity = new PasteboxEntity();
    entity.setId(0L);
    entity.setHash("hash");
    entity.setData("Here's my text #1.");
    entity.setLifeTime(expTime);
    entity.setPublic(true);

    PasteboxEntity entity1 = new PasteboxEntity();
    entity.setId(1L);
    entity.setHash("hash1");
    entity.setData("Here's my text #2.");
    entity.setLifeTime(expTime1);
    entity.setPublic(true);

    PasteboxEntity entity2 = new PasteboxEntity();
    entity.setId(2L);
    entity.setHash("hash2");
    entity.setData("Here's my text #3.");
    entity.setLifeTime(expTime2);
    entity.setPublic(true);

    List<PasteboxEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    entities.add(entity);
    entities.add(entity1);
    entities.add(entity2);

    when(pasteboxJPARepository.findAll()).thenReturn(entities);

    assertEquals(3, pasteboxService.testMethodEntity().size());

}
}
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "paste_box_entities")
public class PasteboxEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;
    @Column(name = "hash")
    private String hash;
    @Column(name = "lifetime")
    private LocalDateTime lifeTime;
    @Column(name = "ispublic")
    private boolean isPublic;
}
```

**Service class**(here I wrote output of all the elements, to see what's going on there)

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PasteboxServiceImpl implements PasteboxService {


    private final PasteboxJPARepository pasteboxJPARepository;

public List<PasteboxEntity> testMethodEntity(){
    
    for(PasteboxEntity e : pasteboxJPARepository.findAll())
        System.out.println(e);
    
    return pasteboxJPARepository.findAll();

}
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface PasteboxJPARepository extends JpaRepository<PasteboxEntity, Long> {
    PasteboxEntity findByHash(String hash);
    List<PasteboxEntity> findAll();
}
```

**And in the console, we can see that, only the first element's not null, although I've initialized everyone.**

[image]

I've tried to find same in the internet, but it seems nothing, so I'm here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting only the fields of `entity`, not `entity1` and `entity2` in your test…

Comment: Gosh... I've lost a few hours of finding out what's going on, thank u :)